# Alfresco: edit documents in custom client

Tags: sharepoint, web-applications, ms-office, alfresco

I'm planning to create a custom small ajax-based webclient to browse some alfresco documents (Word and Excel files).

Is there a way to edit the MS Office files online in a custom web client? Maybe via SharePoint or WebDAV or CIFS Protocol? Can I use the SharePoint protocol for my custom client or is it just for usage in alfresco share?

The environment: Alfresco 3.2, Windows 7, MS Office 2010, IE9, latest Firefox

Answer (score 0):

If u can execute C#/VB then yes.
U have to use :
 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124

and Sharepoint client object model